# How to install locust swarm and work on it in windows?

Tags: locust

I have came across 3rd party tool [locust-swarm](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-swarm). Therefore I went ahead and installed it using command **pip install locust-swarm**.
In the document it is given to run the command **swarm -h** but  when I run it, the command prompt says that command is not recognized. I opened the cmd from the place where swarm file is installed.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is probably related to your PATH environment variable, but locust-swarm is unlikely to work on windows (it is completely untested and relies heavily on linux command line tools like ssh, rsync etc). It could possibly work in something like cygwin.

I am the creator of locust-swarm.

Edit: I have now released an updated package that fails on Windows at install time, so at least that there is no confusion...